# Proper use of IsDisposed in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small win form app that consists of a form and a systray icon.

When the user closes the app from the systray I get the ObjectDisposedException as some controls (task icon) still try and access the main windows form.

I have tried wrapping the code that access the systray in a if(!this.IsDisposed) wrapper, however the check for this is always bypassed.

Am I missing something that I should be doing here?  This seems quite trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code for us SO'ers so that we can answer this for you?

Comment: Is `this` referring to the systray controls, or to the form? At first blush, it seems like you're checking `IsDisposed` on the wrong control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in control of what happens when the user closes the app.  Close things in the right order (based on what forms/controls reference other forms/controls) and you can avoid this problem without hacking in IsDisposed checks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took another look at my code and found I was able to solve this defensively and clean-up all my controls appropriately before I got to that state.